# Need help in writing a assert statement for a test class

Tags: unit-test

I have a class named **'APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler'** and it has a method declared as

`Public Static void updatePLIFromMidCycleApp(List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> proposalLineItems)`

In test class there is a line which is invoking the above method as

```
APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler.updatePLIFromMidCycleApp(pliList);
```

I want to put a assert statement for this line. How can this be done? I have tried various ways but for each of them I get different compile errors.

**Update : Method Code part only**

```
 public static void updatePLIFromMidCycleApp(List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> proposalLineItems) {
        Boolean isSalesUser = false; Boolean isBUUser = false; Boolean isSystemAdmin = false;

        Profile currentUserProfile = [Select Name from Profile where Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()];
        if(currentUserProfile.Name.equalsIgnoreCase(Label.APTPS_SalesProfile) || currentUserProfile.Name.equalsIgnoreCase('Sales')) {
            isSalesUser = true; isBUUser = false;
        } else if(currentUserProfile.Name.equalsIgnoreCase(Label.APTPS_BUProfile) || currentUserProfile.Name.equalsIgnoreCase('BU')) {
            isSalesUser = false; isBUUser = true;
        } else {
            //assume system admin
            isSystemAdmin = true; isBUUser = false; isSalesUser = true;
        }
        //permission set assignments
        if(isSystemAdmin == true) {
            List<PermissionSetAssignment> permissions = [select PermissionSet.Name
                    from PermissionSetAssignment where Assignee.Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
            if(permissions != null && !permissions.isEmpty()) {
                if(permissions[0].PermissionSet.Name == Label.APTPS_PricingSalesPermissionSet) {
                    isSalesUser = true; isBUUser = false;
                } else if(permissions[0].PermissionSet.Name == Label.APTPS_PricingBUPermissionSet) {
                    isSalesUser = false; isBUUser = true;
                } else {
                    isSystemAdmin = true; isBUUser = false; isSalesUser = true;
                }  
            }  
        }  

        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> midCycleLines = new List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();
        Map<Id, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c> mapProposalList = new Map<Id, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c>();
        Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();
        System.debug('***size lines - ' + proposalLineItems.size());
        for(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c pli : proposalLineItems) {
            System.debug('***pli.Publishing_Status__c - ' + pli.Publishing_Status__c);
            if(pli.Publishing_Status__c == 'To Be Published') continue;
            if(isBUUser == true) {
                if(pli.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c >= pli.APTS_Deal_Floor__c) {
                    pli.Publishing_Status__c = 'To Be Published';
                    pli.Bid_Price__c = pli.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c;
                    pli.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c = null;
                }
            }
            System.debug('***pli.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c - ' + pli.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c);
            //mid-cycle app : not setting up flag
            if(pli.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c == true) {
                System.debug('***PLI : ' + pli);
                System.debug('***pli.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c ' + pli.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c);
                midCycleLines.add(pli);
                quoteIds.add(pli.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c);
            }
        }

        if(midCycleLines.isEmpty()) return;    

        //parent proposal list
        if(quoteIds != null && !quoteIds.isEmpty()) {
            mapProposalList = new Map<Id, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c>([Select Id, Name, 
                Apttus_Proposal__ExpectedEndDate__c, APTPS_Contract_Expiration_Date__c, APTPS_BU_Approval_Required__c from
                Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c where Id in :quoteIds]);
        }
        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c> proposalListWithApprovalFlag = new List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c>();    
        Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c parentProposal;
        for(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c lineItem : proposalLineItems) {
            if(lineItem.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c == false) continue;
            if(mapProposalList != null && mapProposalList.get(lineItem.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c) != null) {
                parentProposal = mapProposalList.get(lineItem.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c);
                System.debug('***parentProposal - ' + parentProposal);
            }
            if(isSalesUser == true) {
                System.debug('***isSalesUser - '+ isSalesUser);
                lineItem.APTS_Action_Notes__c = null;
                System.debug('***lineItem.XAE_Action_2__c - out -  ' + lineItem.XAE_Action_2__c);
                if(lineItem.XAE_Action_2__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Expire/Exclude')) {
                    System.debug('***lineItem.XAE_Action_2__c - in -  ' + lineItem.XAE_Action_2__c);
                    System.debug('***llineItem.Publishing_Status__c - in -  ' + lineItem.Publishing_Status__c);
                    if(lineItem.Publishing_Status__c == 'Published') {
                        //don't delete
                        lineItem.APTS_Expired__c = true;
                        lineItem.Publishing_Status__c = 'To Be Published';
                        lineItem.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c = lineItem.Apttus_QPConfig__StartDate__c;
                    } else {
                        //delete it;
                        continue;
                    }
                } else {
                    lineItem.APTS_Include__c = true;
                    lineItem.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c = parentProposal.APTPS_Contract_Expiration_Date__c;
                    System.debug('***Proposal Expire Date - ' + parentProposal.APTPS_Contract_Expiration_Date__c 
                        + ' PLIEnd Date - ' +lineItem.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c);
                }

                System.debug('***New Price - ' + lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c);
                System.debug('***Price Floor - ' + lineItem.Price_Floor__c);
                System.debug('***Deal Floor - ' + lineItem.APTS_Deal_Floor__c);
                if(lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c != null && lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c > 0 
                    && lineItem.Price_Floor__c == null && lineItem.APTS_Deal_Floor__c == null) {
                    //send mail for BU Approval
                    lineItem.Publishing_Status__c = 'Approval Required';
                    if(parentProposal != null && parentProposal.APTPS_BU_Approval_Required__c == false) {
                        parentProposal.APTPS_BU_Approval_Required__c = true;
                        System.debug('***parentProposal Approval required - ' + parentProposal.APTPS_BU_Approval_Required__c);
                        proposalListWithApprovalFlag.add(parentProposal);
                    }
                } else {
                    if((lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c >= lineItem.APTS_Deal_Floor__c) || 
                        (lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c >= lineItem.Price_Floor__c)) {
                        lineItem.Bid_Price__c = lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c;
                        lineItem.Publishing_Status__c = 'To Be Published';
                        lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c = null;
                    } else {
                        if(lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c != null && lineItem.APTS_New_Bid_Price__c > 0
                            && parentProposal != null) {
                            lineItem.Publishing_Status__c = 'Approval Required';
                            if(parentProposal.APTPS_BU_Approval_Required__c == false) {
                                parentProposal.APTPS_BU_Approval_Required__c = true;
                                proposalListWithApprovalFlag.add(parentProposal);
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }
                System.debug('***lineItem.Publishing_Status__c - ' + lineItem.Publishing_Status__c);
            } 
            lineItem.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c = false;
            System.debug('***Midcycle flag - ' + lineItem.APTPS_Is_Mid_Cycle_Context__c);
        }
        if(proposalListWithApprovalFlag != null && !proposalListWithApprovalFlag.isEmpty()) {
            update proposalListWithApprovalFlag; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: please provide more details.

Comment: I have a test class where I have to put assert statements to see whether it is checking the required functionality or not. That test class creates data with the utility class. So I have main class with 700 lines of code, test class of 300 lines and utility class with 500 lines. It will be difficult to post full code here. What I want there is just an assert statement for the line  APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler.updatePLIFromMidCycleApp(pliList);  If by posting just the "updatePLIFromMidCycleAp" method is sufficient  then let me know I'll post that.

Comment: share that code.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: you are using this list `proposalLineItems` for update . So check `assert.equals(proposalLineItems[0].some field == updateedvalue)`

Comment: did your problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using this list proposalLineItems for update . So check

```
assert.equals(proposalLineItems[0].some field == updatedvalue).
```

This will solve your problem.